# Why is the parallel array version of the below slower than the regular one

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, f#

I am investigating speeding up processing of large datasets using multiple cores. The following test code yields a surprising result, namely that the parallel code version is approx 3x slower than the single core implementation. Why would that be?

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let n = 200000000
    let xs = [|1..n|]

    let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    stopWatch.Start()
    let ys1 = xs |> Array.map (fun x -> x * 10)
    stopWatch.Stop()
    printfn "%A" stopWatch.Elapsed

    System.GC.Collect(2)

    let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    stopWatch.Start()
    let ys2 = xs |> Array.Parallel.map (fun x -> x * 10)
    stopWatch.Stop()
    printfn "%A" stopWatch.Elapsed

    printfn "%A" argv
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

The results are as follows:

> 00:00:00.3471365
>
> 00:00:00.9448111
>
> [||]
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

I have set the compile options to a 64 bit application with optimization preferred.

## UPDATE

Per suggestion below, I changed the lambda function to something more complex akin to `exp(100.78 + sin x + 89.6*log x)` and got the results expected - parallel is much faster.

Comment: FYI; assuming you have 4 cores in the parallell version is actually 3x4 times slower. One way to reduce the overhead of parallell processing is to increase the amount of work in the work unit (like suggested). Sometimes that can mean processing more than one element in the work unit. It's also bad to increase it too much as then you lose parallellism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do parallel there is some overhead per task, for example, each task has to be dispatched to a thread and then results collected.

In series, there is much less overhead.

When the task is as simple as `x*10`. the overhead dominates.

For a more complex task, the parallel will be faster